# Use Two Different Adapters in One Model

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I want to use mongo to store a global feed's data but I want to cache the most recent posts in memory with redis. Is there a way to set up one model to use two adapters? If there isn't I think I'm going to try to have one controller use two models.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an experimental feature, but you *can* have a single model use multiple connections, and the connections can use different adapters:

In a Sails v0.9.x model, with `mongo` and `redis` defined in `/config/adapters.js`:

```
module.exports = {

    adapter: ['mongo', 'redis']
    attributes: {...}

}
```

In a Sails v0.10.x model, with `mongo` and `redis` defined in `/config/connections.js`:

```
module.exports = {

    connections: ['mongo', 'redis']
    attributes: {...}

}
```

However, you can't specify that some attributes use one connection, and other attributes use another.  If more than one adapter is involved, and the adapters have identical methods, then they will be merged together.  This would be the case for using `sails-mongo` and `sails-redis` in the same model; both adapters have `find`, `create`, `update` and `destroy`, so your model would end up using only one of the adapters' methods (`sails-redis`, in the example above).

What's the use of multiple adapters then?  It's a way to add external API methods to a model.  For example, if you had a `File` model representing a file living on Amazon S3, you could use a `sails-s3` adapter with `upload` and `download` methods, alongside `sails-mongo` to store metadata about the file.

Caching is also a feature which is in [active development](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/200), but in the meantime your best bet would be to use a separate model for the cache, as you suggested.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. It would be nice to pick and choose between attributes (for each post in redis I'll want the username, the user's image and some other specific data while I think I would want to only have the user id in my mongo db) but this should be good enough.

Comment: To specify what I meant by "I would only want the user id in my mongo db" I meant I would only want the user's id stored on their posts.

Comment: Is this still experimental or could I use it in a production app?